# How to limit width of html site?

Tags: html

How do I set the width of a web page to always be exactly 1000px ? For example, like Facebook or here on StackOverflow. The site just will not resize. If the browser window is smaller than 1000px, the scroll bar is needed. And the page should be centered in the browser.

I can always put content of the page inside `<div></div>` tags, but I have read that it will not work for all browsers. So what is the right way to do it ?

Comment: May be set width in `<body>` tag.

Comment: `<div>` tag is supported by all browsers, it's the core of HTML.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enclosing the content in a `div` that has the CSS `width` property set to `1000px` will work across browsers.

CSS:

```
div.content { width: 1000px }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
  ...
  </div>
<body>
```

However, consider using 960 pixels instead of 1000. It is a reliable standard that works on most devices down to a 1024 pixel display width including space for scroll bars and such.

Answer (score 5):

Directly set the body to display at that width:

```
body {
   width:1000px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

However, I usually use a wrap div as follows:

**html**

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap"></div>
<body>
```

**css**

```
div.wrap {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```